# Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library

In our production front end server, sometimes when a user uploads a document file into SharePoint 2010 document library we are getting the error below:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error  Description: An application error occurred on the
>   server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent
>   the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for
>   security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on
>   the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within
>   a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This  tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> ```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration> <system.web> <customErrors mode="Off"/> </system.web>
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.
>
> ```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration> <system.web> <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"
> defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/> </system.web> </configuration>
> ```

Things we checked in SharePoint

- Upload Size in SharePoint’s Central Admin
- Time-out settings in IIS as same the default value is 120
- Update SharePoint Web Application web.config as `executionTimeout="999999"`

There is no custom pages nothing.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You must look in the ULS logs (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210652.aspx) for details information, your error message is way to generic for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for reply.. checked in Event viewer logged as Event 5586 (SharePoint Foundation) of severity 'Error' occurred 784 more time(s) and was suppressed in the event log.

Comment: possibly trying to upload a file that is on the blocked extension lest?